# How to make a variable containing all the rest parameter from nth particular parameter

Tags: bash, shell

How to make a variable containing all the rest parameter from nth particular parameter, for instance the string holds all data from 3rd parameter until 9th parameter is within a variable named $a... Thanks in advance.

Comment: How should the parameters be separated in the variable? Spaces? Pipe?

Comment: as usual; space that's not surrounded by (double) quotes

Answer (score 1):

In Bash/ksh/zsh, you can use something like `${@:3:7}` to get the 3rd to 9th parameters as distinct words, or `${*:3:7}` to get them concatenated with the first character of `IFS` as joiner. (7, since there's seven in total from 3 to 9.)

so:

```
$ set -- $(seq 11 21)
$ echo "${*:3:7}"
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

or

```
$ a="${*:3:7}"
```

However, if you want to pass those arguments as parameters to another command, use `"${@:3:7}"` directly on the command line in question, i.e.

```
somecmd "${@:3:7}"
```

If you need to do this in standard shell, you can't use `${var:n:m}`. Instead you would need to `shift` the first arguments away, and then use `"$@"`, so:

```
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
shift 2
somecmd "$@"
```